# Struggling with if statements for pandas df: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all()

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, for-loop, if-statement

Here is a bit of context to my code, and the main line of issue below it. Even replacing `and` with `&` did not work

```
df['in_uptrend'] = 'N/A'
    for current in range(1, len(df.index)):
        previous = current - 1
... 

#MAIN ISSUE
if df['short_ema'][current] < df['long_ema'][current] and df['close'][current] < df['short_ema'][current] and df['above_below_50'] == 'below_50' and in_short == False:
            df['in_uptrend'][current] = 'OPEN SHORT'
            in_short = True
```

This gives the error:

```
ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().
```

and below that:

```
TypeError: catching classes that do not inherit from BaseException is not allowed
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Standard python-based `if-else` works for singular boolean values. When working with dataframes, comparing series tends to produce a boolean series or list of values. Hence the error.

The error also hints to use `empty`, `bool()`, `item()`, `any()`, `all()`. These function trivially convert a series of boolean values into a single boolean value. Then it can be used in an `if-else` statement.

If you are trying to fetch one item of a series use `loc`:

```
# df.loc[index, column]
df.loc[current, 'short_ema']
```

Use vectorized functions instead. Like,

```
df['in_uptrend'] = (
    df['short_ema'] < df['long_ema'] &
    df['close'] < df['short_ema'] &
    df['above_below_50'] == 'below_50'
)
```

Comment: right. Have you got a suggestion on what to use instead?

Comment: Ideally, I won't iterate. Use vectorized functions @HamishMcP